# Mono HttpListener on OSX won't release port

Tags: c#, macos, mono, httplistener

I have a simple HttpListener on Mono 3.2 on OSX.

```
 listener = new HttpListener();
 listener.Prefixes.Add(listenerUrlPrefix.FormatWith(emailGuid));
 listener.Start();

...do some stuff to listen 

if (listener != null)
{
    listener.Prefixes.Clear();
    listener.Stop();
    listener.Close();
    listener = null;
}
```

However after the above code executes, I still see the port in use

```
COMMAND     PID          USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mono-sgen 23718 administrator    8u  IPv4 0xe9923e6b20e4a19d      0t0  TCP localhost:palace-1 (LISTEN)
```

The code i wrote will eventually want to spin up a new HttpListener, and I'm seeing in some instances or on some machines (this is an application that's running out on lots of machines) where it takes 5-6s to do listener.Start().  Any ideas?

Comment: This is a complete guess, but have you tried disposing of the object? It's possible bits of it's internal implementation are released in there. For this type of thing I would always use the pattern `using (listener = new HttpListener) { /*/ }`. This will automatically fire the instances `Dispose()` method at the end of the block, ensuring it's cleaned up properly. Worth a try, certainly, and better practice even if it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: if I try to call Dispose() I get "Cannot access explicit implementation of IDispose()" at compile-time. Also, I would like to state that the 'do some stuff' logic is pretty spread out such that using a 'using' block isn't feasible.

Comment: For reasons best known HttpListener explicitly implements IDIsposible so you'd have to either use a using block or cast to IDisposible, but it would appear Close does everything important Dispose does anyway. Sadly the root of the problem appears to be something more complicated.. Before you null the object can you check if Close has been successful? Are you using the synchronous or async methods?

Comment: Most of these calls are Async actually. We end up serving images in an async function as request(s) come in; when we've gotten all expected images, we close the listener up. 

Sadly I don't think HttpListener exposes anything I can check; Stop is synchronous I think this is a vagary of the mono implementation of this. 

If you check https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpListener.cs you can see that Stop calls Close() but its unclear why the port is still listening.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I'm not seeing any easy way of checking the status. My assumption would be that close is not happening immediately because one of the async calls hasn't finished yet. I note though that the public `Close()` method calls the private `Close(bool force)` method with force as true, but only if the `disposed` bool is still false. Have you tried simply removing the Stop? It might allow it to force the `Close`. If not you could try `Abort()` instead to force anything that's still waiting to end.

Comment: Wow, Octopoid, you definitely lead me down the right direction. It's weird, yes, if you call 'Stop()' in the mono implementation sets 'disposed' as true, which short circuits the Close(true). In fact, it looks like the Close() method will wait around for the GC. I've branched my code and on mono I'll call Abort() which will stop and close with the actual close. Preliminary results are promising but I will leave this open for now. I'll also see about making a pull request and contributing to mono to fix.

Comment: Bug filed with mono team: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28771